# Using qemu-system-gnuarmeclipse command-line for nrf52840

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, qemu, cortex-m, nrf52

I want to run unit-tests for a firmware code written for nrf52840 using QEMU. I came across the GNU MCU Eclipse project which has forked the main QEMU project to provide better support for Cortex-M SoCs by allowing the creation of cortex-m devices through data definitions provided in CMSIS SVD files (as noted [here](https://github.com/gnu-mcu-eclipse/qemu/tree/gnuarmeclipse-dev/gnu-mcu-eclipse/devices)). Even though the project primarily supports the STM32 based boards and MCUs, their eclipse plugin does support adding new device packs for development and debugging. But I am not able to figure out how to use their command-line tool ***qemu-system-gnuarmeclipse*** to run an ELF file created for nrf52840. I have the following questions:

1. How does eclipse plugin allow debugging for nrf52840 using custom SVD file even though their command-line tool doesn't have any option to provide a custom SVD file?
2. How can I add support for nrf52840? Can I reuse board and MCU definitions for STM32 and just provide a JSON variant for SVD file [here](https://github.com/gnu-mcu-eclipse/qemu/tree/gnuarmeclipse-dev/gnu-mcu-eclipse/devices)?

Answer (score -1):

See the discussion [here](https://www.element14.com/community/thread/73802) for response to this question

Comment: Perfect example of why link-only answers are bad - the link is dead.